# SharePoint 2010 - How do I assign a different masterpage to my calendar.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, calendar

I need to understand how i can assign a custom master page to a calendar list in sharepoint 2010. In other lists I have used a schema and setup path but i can't figure out how to do it for a calendar list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to change the specified masterpage by opening the form in SharePoint designer.

The beginning of the first line should be fairly similar to this...

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" .......
```

Just change the MasterPageFile to a path pointing to the masterpage you want to use and make any changes in the page itself that you may need to support the new masterpage.

Comment: thanks but i needed to do it via visual studio so i could create deployable solutions across platforms. i added a setup path to my schema for a list that assigns a custom master page